# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm running SAP Hybris Commerce Suite 6.1.
I'm facing a problem at application startup, can someone help me with this?

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter cuppytrailfrontendPlatformFilterChain
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext - /cuppytrailfrontend: startup date [Tue Jan 31 16:35:43 PST 2017]; parent: hybris Application context - master
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:130)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.findWebApplicationContext(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:307)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:234)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5542)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post more details of what you've done after generating the cuppy trail front end extension? Does it happen right after you create the extensions? What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Check the application context configuration in the cuppytrailfrontend extension: spring configuration files. There're any attributes with wrong declared type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with spring version. Spring 4 is being support since Hybris 5.5. Just check if cuppy trail is having older spring version. Update it with spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

Tried removing the spring4* jar from web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib and it got worked.